# Stable set for $f(x) = \frac{\pi}{2}\sin(x)$

Tags: trigonometry, nonlinear-system, nonlinear-dynamics

So, i've been thinking about this question to find out what is the stable set for $f(x) = \frac{\pi}{2}\sin(x)\,,\,0\leq x \leq \pi$. More specifically, my question is: is there a way that we could represent the iterations of $\sin{(x)}$, for example $\sin{(\sin{(x)})}$, $\sin{(\sin{\cdots\sin{(x)}})}$, in the unit circle? That is to say, if we know that we are drawing a vertical line for the representation of $\sin{(x)}$ in the unit circle, what will happen with the subsequent lines representing further iterations of this particular function?

Comment: Are you iterating $\sin(x)$ or $f(x) = \frac{\pi}{2}\sin(x)$?

Comment: Sorry, i'm iterating $f(x) = \frac{\pi}{2}\sin{(x)}$.

Comment: The challenge with visualizing this on the unit circle is that the input to a trig function must be interpreted as an angle (length of piece arc around the circle) whereas the output is a rectilinear measurement. If you can imagine measuring out a length (vertically, say, as the output of the sine function), then scaling it, before wrapping it around the circle for the next iteration, then this works but this is tough to [visualize](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/qn52mmxatt).

Comment: @SammyBlack man! Thank you so much!

Comment: it's fine, @hardmath, people really helped me answering the question. In the past week i've managed to solve this problem. So thank you guys so much!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your angles are in $(-\pi, \pi]$, there are two stable points: $\pm \pi/2$ (and one unstable point: $0$). This can be seen by plotting $y=x$ and $y=f(x)=\frac{\pi}{2}\sin x$ on the same graph.

You can visualise the convergence in a staircase-like pattern ([example](https://www.mathscard.co.uk/files/figures/42.png)) There is some theory on such convergences based on the first and second derivatives of $f$.

In this case it's easy: all $x\in (0,\pi]$ have $f^n(x)\to\pi/2$.

Comment: Yes, if we draw like $g(x) = x$ we can see this staircase-like pattern that you are talking about, if we draw horizontal lines going from the function $f(x)$ to $g(x)$, and repeating the procedure. But i was running into trouble when trying to proove things like for which values of $x$ does $\frac{\pi}{2}\sin{(\frac{\pi}{2}\sin{(x)})}>\sin{(x)}$.

Comment: I think you're trying to prove $f^2(x)>f(x)$? Well, clearly $f(x')>x'$ on $(0,\pi/2)$, (and then let $x'=f(x)$) and exploit the symmetry of $f$ about $\pi/2$.

Comment: Yes, exactly what you're saying. Thank you so much for the this last comment. I'll try to work this out.